# Delete Items from ListView in cursoradapter

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, android-cursoradapter

i created a custom list with textbox and image. Image should delete row in database sqlite.

in my fragment activity I am using the query method of sqlitedatabase.

```
cursor = mSqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT liked_id as _id, liked_presentation_id FROM liked", null);
LikedListCursorAdapter likedListCursorAdapter = new LikedListCursorAdapter(getActivity(), cursor);
lvItems.setAdapter(likedListCursorAdapter);
```

/////////////my cursoradapter

```
public class LikedListCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

SQLiteDatabase mSqLiteDatabase;
int idSpeaker,idPresentation;
TextView textViewName, textViewCompany, textViewTitle, textViewDate, textViewAboutReport;
LinearLayout linearLayout;

   public static ImageView imageViewStatus;
    private DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper;

public LikedListCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    super(context, cursor);

}


@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.liked_list, parent, false);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, final Context context, final Cursor cursor) {

    imageViewStatus = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageViewStatus);

    textViewTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
    textViewDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewTime);

    idSpeaker = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));

///////////////delete item

    imageViewStatus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.w("id",String.valueOf(idSpeaker));
            mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);

            mSqLiteDatabase = mDatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();

            mSqLiteDatabase.delete(mDatabaseHelper.TABLE_LIKED,
                    "liked_id = ?",
                    new String[] {String.valueOf(idSpeaker)});
            cursor.requery();


            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

however, always remove the last row in the listView. ( position of cursor is last).

I don't know how get current position from listview, when i click. Please, help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

I added code for finding position of cursor before setOnClickListener.

```
final int position = cursor.getPosition();



 imageViewStatus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int idSpeaker;

                mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
                mSqLiteDatabase = mDatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();


/////move to this position

                cursor.moveToPosition(position);
                idSpeaker = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("liked_id"));

                Log.w("getPos",String.valueOf(cursor.getPosition()));
                mSqLiteDatabase.delete(mDatabaseHelper.TABLE_LIKED,
                        "liked_id = ?",
                        new String[] {String.valueOf(idSpeaker)});
                cursor.requery();


                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You are initializing your `idSpeaker` in your bindView, which always gives you last id of your data. so when you are deleting from you table your last item is deleted.

You only need to shift your one line

`idSpeaker = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));`

from bind view to

```
    imageViewStatus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           cursor.moveToPosition(position);
           idSpeaker = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));

            Log.w("id",String.valueOf(idSpeaker));
            mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);

            mSqLiteDatabase = mDatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();

            mSqLiteDatabase.delete(mDatabaseHelper.TABLE_LIKED,
                    "liked_id = ?",
                    new String[] {String.valueOf(idSpeaker)});
            cursor.requery();


            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

Comment: it's not working. cursor.getposition() = last index in listview

As far as I understand, i need find index row in listview and transfer it to cursor.movetoposition(index); 
then will work

Comment: add this 
cursor.moveToPosition(position) before idSpeaker